# Python 2.7.6 variables scoping: strange behavior

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I wrote an example code:

```
def fun():
    print x
    l = [x for x in range(100)]
    print x

x = 1
fun()
```

It gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scope.py", line 7, in <module>
    fun()
  File "scope.py", line 2, in fun
    print x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

But if I comment out the third line like this:

```
def fun():
    print x
    #l = [x for x in range(100)]
    print x

x = 1
fun()
```

it prints out:

```
1
1
```

What's happening there? Why does `l = [x for x in range(100)]` have such an effect in `fun()`?

Comment: Because that list comprehension is an implicit assignment to `x`; note that this wouldn't happen in 3.x, where list comprehensions have their own scope.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are having this issue is due to the way python looks for variables (Closures). First when you start with `x = 1` the x outside fun() is 1 but inside fun() there is no "x" so the function then looks outside the function and sees the `x = 1` to get the value. When you do `l = [x for x in range(100)]` you have no initialized the variable x to run the loop and because of that it fails to compile (i.e. it doesn't look outside the function and says x not defined)

Comment: If you want to access a global variable with the same name as a local, use `global var_name` before you access the variable to refer to the global variable.

Comment: he could @user161151 but generally it's not advisable since it'll be prone to downstream errors and bugs, code smell

Comment: I still don't understand fully. Isn't Python code compiled line by line during execution? Then why does list comprehension in the next line breaks variable resolution for `print x` _before it_? Or the `fun()` function is first compiled completely and only then run?